# How send connection string in Identity 3?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

In `Identity` 2 i see thats it get several params

```
 public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }
```

[image]

But in `Identity 3` its not get params. How i can send connectionString?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In asp.net core, you have to override OnConfiguring:

```
  protected override void OnConfiguring ( DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
 {
   var connString = ""; 

   optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connString);

   base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
}
```